# How to align button horizontally in primefaces column?

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I am having a layout problem in one of my primefaces UI.
I basically have a table wrapped in a DIV with the code below.  The last column should contain buttons that I wanted to arrange horizontally
so I enclosed them in a panelGroup

```
<div style="overflow: auto; height: 300px;">
    <p:dataTable >
        <p:column headerText="Column 1">
        </p:column>
        .
        .
        <p:column headerText="Actions">
            <h:panelGroup layout="span">
                <p:commandButton value="Edit" icon="ui-icon-scissors" />
                <p:commandButton value="Delete" icon="ui-icon-trash" />
            </h:panelGroup>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</div>
```

However, when they are rendered the buttons are arrange vertically.  Viewing the HTML code I notice that the buttons are both wrapped in a div
so thats why there is a newline between them.

How to fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: what is your PrimeFaces version? on 3.4.1, with your code they are wrapped into the same div.

Comment: I updated my answer with an alternative `h:panelGroup` solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrap them with a `<h:panelGrid/>` or a `<p:panelGroup/>`. This will render a `table` with two table cells in the same table row (so they must be appear in the same row):

With `h:panelGrid`:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <p:commandButton value="Edit" icon="ui-icon-scissors" />
    <p:commandButton value="Delete" icon="ui-icon-trash" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

With `h:panelGroup`:

If you use `h:panelGroup` without style, styleClass or id attributes the `layout` attribute has no effect and no additional html will be rendered around your buttons. Anyway, adding the style:

```
<h:panelGroup style="white-space: nowrap">
    ....
</h:panelGroup>
```

makes them horizontally aligned, no matter which `layout` value you are using.

Comment: I think the last `panelGroup` it's not correctly closed. Should be... `</h:panelGroup>`

Comment: Thanks, fixed after 9 years. :)

Comment: It's never too late when it comes to Java